# How Can I add an icon next to anchor tag in HTML email?

Tags: html, css, anchor, html-email

How can I have an image (little arrow on the right) set next to an anchor tag `<a>` and keep them both aligned vertically and horizontally. I've been trying this in multiple ways but came across errors with every method I tried. either the `<a>` tag wont work (not clickable) in `html` emails or the arrow would be outside the clickable area. I only need one of these following codes .Here's some what Iv'e tried:

**First code:** the problem here is: if the user clicked on the arrow it wont response, because it's not inside the `<a>` tag, but this is working

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#007cb0; font-weight: normal;text-align: center;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;  vertical-align: top; line-height: normal !important;">
            <a style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">Go to Link</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right" style="text-align: left; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="15"></td>
          <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/5/007cb0" width="5" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Second code:** I couldn't get the text vertical aligned within the `<td>`

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#007cb0; font-weight: normal;text-align: center;">
        <tr>
          <td height="50" align="left" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;  vertical-align: top; line-height: 100% !important;">
            <a style="height:100%;font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer; display: block">Go to Link <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="20" style="vertical-align: middle;"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Third code** The problem here is: It didn't work in any email client and the link is not clickable.

```html
<table class="mobile" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#007cb0; font-weight: normal;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 20px;display: block; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">
                <tr style="font-size: 16px; text-align: left; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">
                  <td align="left" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;  vertical-align: top; line-height: normal !important;">
                    GET VERSATILE
                  </td>
                  <td align="right" style="text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="15" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Summaries:**

**I need this `<a>` tag to have an arrow next to it and to be Clickable all around the blue area.**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working in most of email clients, and even if I changed the text inside the anchor tag.

hope that would help.

```html
<table class="mobile" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#007cb0;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
        <tr>
          <td class="links" style="padding: 10px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;"><a style="text-align: center; display: block;cursor: pointer;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: none; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: bold;" pm-link="landingpage1" pm-link-default-url="global_landingpage">GO TO LINK<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/15/007cb0" width="15" alt="" /><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="20" style="vertical-align: middle;padding: 0 0 4px 0;max-width: 20px" /></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Now that I know you're making a button that aligns to the right, I have a better approach for you.

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right">
  <tr>
    <td><!-- The button code --> 
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="background: #007cb0; text-align: center;">
              <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: #007cb0; 
              border: 15px solid #007cb0; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; 
              line-height: 110%; text-align: center; text-decoration: none !important; 
              display: block; font-weight: 700;"><span style="color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Go to Link&nbsp;<img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="15">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code will right-align and look presentable in every email client. It does not quite look perfect in Outlook. To do that, you need to add a spacer table specifically for Outlook.

I am deleting the older post and code, but honestly, it's the same thing I posted yesterday with added `&nbsp;` which gives you a reliable form of padding.

Comment: The link is good but I found out first hand VML's have started having issues in newer sub-versions of Outlook 2017 (windows). I found an easier button (just tables and `a` tag).

Comment: I do appreciate your help, but this is how I started and kept adding styles to make look the same on most of the clients, but then I got stuck at the point were the button doesn't click or the arrow is not aligned or there's no padding....etc

Comment: @Adam What I posted will fit into your table to right-align and work. Your code did not work in Outlook, iPhones and a few others. Doing buttons is really hard. If that's what you're doing, I can post a better example.

Comment: Please do, because thats what Im looking for. I need the button to work in most of clients. thank you

Comment: @Adam Above in my answer is updated code. I tested it in Litmus and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have thought of this but it should be as easy as adding an `a` tag around the image for the first question.

Try this below and see if it works for you. I have just added your a tag from the sibling td just to give you an idea.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="33%" align="right" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#007cb0; font-weight: normal;text-align: center;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;  vertical-align: top; line-height: normal !important;">
            <a style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">Go to Link</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right" style="text-align: left; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="15"></td>
          <td><a style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/5/007cb0" width="5" /></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this answer works for you.

Comment: This button has four problems: 
1. it doesn't work when I click on the arrow.
2. it's smaller in Android 6.0 than the rest of mobile and clients
3. it look different in Outlook 2013 win 7.
4. it has two anchor tags and I only need one.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Android smaller because you are using width 33%, this can be controlled thru media queries. Use background color with transparent image and it should look better.  You have two elements text and image. The alignment will always be off in different devices if not placed as two.

Comment: If you want the same height on both then you will need line height, font size and image size right. But this still doesn't qurantee the same rendering across all devices.

Comment: Im not worried about his problem, I want to solve the issue with the button first. If you look at my third code: this could be perfect if I can make it work inside the email. but the button is not clickable for some reason

Comment: It's because you are wrapping an inline element around a table. Outlook doesn't like it and doesn't render the a tag but everything else. Outlook will not render a tag around a table as far as I know

Comment: yeah, so I tired everything so far and haven't find the perfect way yet. to go with.some clients don't like padding, etc.. however all I want is to have this arrow next to the `<a>` and make them aligned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171560/discussion-between-adam-and-syfer).

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell why are you using table formatting for making button-styled links?  Is that specific for html-email? This seems easier and after some customizing will give the same look:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Link <span> &#x276F;</span></a>
```

Comment: Not supported by outlook 2010 2007

Answer (score -1):

OK then just add/adjust margin and padding to make clickable area larger

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: -1em;
}

td img{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33q09cy0/

and add the image inside the a tag reference.

```
<td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 30px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;  vertical-align: top; line-height: normal !important;">
        <a style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; cursor: pointer;">Go to Link</a>
        <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/ffffff/forward.png" width="15">
</td>
```

Comment: This is not supported by most of the email clients. check this [link for email support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/after/)

Comment: Most email clients do not support `position` or `z-index` as valid css. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/ - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/z-index/

Comment: well you want a css answer with basically no css involved, kind of defeats the purpose lol

Comment: it didn't work for some email clients, as the position is not supported. Check this [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/)